# Confuse about python cooperation syntax

Tags: python, odoo-9

I saw this code in a module of odoo and it makes me so confuse to understand how it's working

```
invisible': [('state', '!=', 'draft'), ('communication', '=', False)]
```

I understand that **invisible** 'll return true|false based on 2 conditions : **('state', '!=', 'draft')** and  **('communication', '=', False)**. The first condition 'll return true when 'state' different 'draft' and false when 'state' is 'draft'. But what 's happen in the second condition and operator between 2 conditions is OR or AND

This is whole code of this

```
 <field name="communication" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'draft'), ('communication', '=', False)], 'readonly': [('state', '!=', 'draft')]}"/>
```

Please help me to explain this piece of code that how it's working

Comment: This is a Python list of tuples that will be used by some code (in Odoo, I guess, since you tagged your question Odoo) following a logic that depends only on that code. Understanding this requires further knowledge of that specific code.

Comment: I don't think this is a list of tuples because invisible is a attribute, it must return true false

Comment: You're not showing enough code. `invisible` seems to be a string, probably a dict key, the tuple list being the associated value in the dict. You should quote more of the surrounding code.

Comment: There must be some code in Odoo that processes this dict to return True or False.

Comment: Maybe someone knowing Odoo's insides can help. You could add a link to that specific Odoo module and to the line of code. It might help.

Comment: I found the answer on odoo forum : https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/attrs-multiple-condition-boolean-and-17889
tks for your help :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For using 'AND' simply use -

```
invisible': [('state', '!=', 'draft'), ('communication', '=', False)]
```

and in case of 'OR' use -

```
invisible': ['|', ('state', '!=', 'draft'), ('communication', '=', False)]
```

using pipe "|" will help you getting one condition true.